# Jena Fuseki SPARQL INSERT in PHP (EasyRDF lib)

Tags: php, rdf, fuseki, easyrdf, graph-store-protocol

I'm trying to run the sample code from the EasyRDF library with Apache Jena Fuseki, but the following error occurs when entering data into the database:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'EasyRdf_Exception' with message 'HTTP
>   request for
>   http:// localhost:3030/test/update?graph=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3030%2Ftest%2Ftime.rdf
>   failed: Must be application/sparql-update or
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded (got application/n-triples)' in
>   D:\Files\xampp\htdocs\test\easyrdf-0.9.0\lib\EasyRdf\GraphStore.php:152
>   Stack trace: #0
>   D:\Files\xampp\htdocs\test\easyrdf-0.9.0\lib\EasyRdf\GraphStore.php(217):
>   EasyRdf_GraphStore->sendGraph('POST', Object(EasyRdf_Graph),
>   'time.rdf', 'ntriples') #1
>   D:\Files\xampp\htdocs\test\graphstore.php(34):
>   EasyRdf_GraphStore->insert(Object(EasyRdf_Graph), 'time.rdf') #2
>   {main} thrown in
>   D:\Files\xampp\htdocs\test\easyrdf-0.9.0\lib\EasyRdf\GraphStore.php on
>   line 152

Follow the code:

```html
<?php
    set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '../lib/');
    require_once "easyrdf-0.9.0/lib/EasyRdf.php";
?>
<html>
<head>
  <title>GraphStore example</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
  // Use a local SPARQL 1.1 Graph Store (eg RedStore)
  $gs = new EasyRdf_GraphStore('http://localhost:3030/test/update');

  // Add the current time in a graph
  $graph1 = new EasyRdf_Graph();
  $graph1->add('http://example.com/test', 'rdfs:label', 'Test');
  $graph1->add('http://example.com/test', 'dc:date', time());
  $gs->insert($graph1, 'time.rdf');

  // Get the graph back out of the graph store and display it
  $graph2 = $gs->get('time.rdf');
  print $graph2->dump();
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up the [SPARQL 1.1 Protocol](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-protocol/) and the [SPARQL 1.1 Graph Store HTTP Protocol](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-http-rdf-update/).
The difference is that the latter doesn't use SPARQL queries to perform operations on RDF graphs.

For every protocol, Fuseki exposes two URIs: for read and for write operations.

[image]

Thus, if you want to use the **SPARQL 1.1 Graph Store HTTP Protocol**, you should write:

```php
$gs = new EasyRdf_GraphStore('http://localhost:3030/test/data');
```

instead of

```php
$gs = new EasyRdf_GraphStore('http://localhost:3030/test/update');
```

---

If you need to use the **SPARQL 1.1 Protocol**, write something like this:

```php
<?php
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'easyrdf-0.9.0/lib/');
require_once "EasyRdf.php";

$endpoint = new EasyRdf_Sparql_Client('http://localhost:3030/test/query',
                                      'http://localhost:3030/test/update');

function insert_data() {
    global $endpoint;
    $result = $endpoint->update("
        PREFIX : <http://example.org/> 
        INSERT DATA {:alice :knows :bob. :alice :name 'alice'. :bob :name 'bob'}"
    );
}
function insert_where() {
    global $endpoint;
    $result = $endpoint->update ("
        PREFIX : <http://example.org/> 
        INSERT {?s :loves ?o}
        WHERE {?s :name 'bob'. ?o :name 'alice'}"
    );
}
function select_where() {
    global $endpoint;
    $result = $endpoint->query("
        SELECT * WHERE {?s ?p ?o}"
    );
    print ($result->numRows()); 
}

insert_data();   select_where();
insert_where();  select_where();

?>
```

Sources:

- [SPARQL 1.1 Update](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/)
- [EasyRdf_Sparql_Client](http://www.easyrdf.org/docs/api/EasyRdf_Sparql_Client.html)

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43475640/7879193) for some details.